# loading web fonts in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, fonts, web, hosting

I have been doing asp.net web development for a while but never implemented a complete asp.net website and hosted it. I have been working on an asp.net web site and hosted it on windows server.

I have couple of custom web fonts (paid fonts) which i am using in the site. I have included the files for the web fonts and styles in my project folder and referenced them properly in my style sheet.

I have used the @font-face in referring the fonts in my style sheet:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fontname';
src: url('/fonts/webfonts/font.eot');
src: url('/fonts/webfonts/font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/fonts/webfonts/font.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/webfonts/font.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

But, the web fonts are not being loaded in the web site.

After some research I found we need to add the mime type in web.config type for windows server to recognize that format of fonts. Then, I also referenced the mime types in the web.config file as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But, it is also not working. Can anyone please let me know, how can we load those fonts.

Answer (score 2):

So you also need to add a MIME mapping for `.eot` and `.ttf`?

The similar block we have in our `Web.config` files reads:

```xml
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-truetype"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
</staticContent>
```

Note that we remove any mappings first, just in case they get configured upstream at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Other link
[problems with parameters on url for fontawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429519/font-awesome-error-downloadable-font-rejected-by-sanitizer) which I saw suggested removing parameters
instead of:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
```

use:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```