# Font Awesome error: downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-awesome

> downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "FontAwesome"
>   style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1) source:
>   http://192.168.1.254/theme/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 http://192.168.1.254/theme/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Line
>   4

I was keep getting above error. and i tried lots of stuff found on the internet. (hosting the fonts on own server)

- CORS issue
- MIME-type header config in web server

Other combinations of HTTP headers and MIME-types everything that can resolve the issue but nothing solved it.

Comment: Did not work for me: this post did solve the error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104736/networkerror-404-not-found-fontawesome-webfont-woffv-4-0-3

Comment: @leonvr as i said, even after updating Mime Types if don't work, this might be the reason. yours one certainly must be stuck at mimetypes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove the `?v=4.6.3` and remaining tail from this block (`font-awesome.css` / `font-awesome.min.css`).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
```

Updated to:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: @mayaa, in my case it was due to; my web server was not accepting/expecting any attached parameters (using GET, but using POST i don't know) with the above url calls.

Comment: I saw errors in Chrome, such as iis returning 404.htm related to some of these file fontawesome related requests until making this change

Answer (score 4):

Catched !!
Solved with replacing

```
font-family: 'fontawesome-webfont';
```

instead of

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
```

I works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 not found but you definitely know you have the file, here is how to fix it in IIS:

You need to add the mime type in the config file for woff2.

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your answer did the trick!
I got this error on IIS 8 (W2012) but on IIS 10 (w2016) everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a problem with a SVG loader (either vue-svg-loader or nuxt-svg-loader) that ended up converting the font URL into an object resulting in something like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:fontello;
    ...
    src:url([object object]) format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the best answer doesnt work for u, can consider checking if the fonts folder is present.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue today.
Fixing that path in @font-face 's src resolved the issue. If you encounter a similar error, check to make sure that the path to your font file is correct.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url("../../fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Light.ttf");
    
  /* src: url("../../fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Light.woff"); */
}
```